# Deploy to production server failed due to code coverage error

Tags: apex, force.com, ide, delete, production

I have deployed two new apex classes to production via the change sets and am trying to use the IDE to delete the other classes from production that are no longer needed and are ruining the code coverage.  Because the code coverage is so rubbish I can't deploy the deleted classes via the IDE.

I have followed all of the steps listed here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006188 and this has worked in the past for me, but this time I'm getting a code coverage error, which seems silly as I'm trying to delete all of the code which is causing the error and leaving 2 classes (one is the test class which has 100% code coverage).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Seems you are deleted the test class and that covered the latest deployed two class. Right  ?

Comment: I'm trying to delete these classes: OpportunityTriggerHandler, Test_DataUtilityClass, Test_OpportunityTriggerHandler and this trigger: OpportunityTrigger.  This would leave only two classes: AutoNumberPatternChecker and AutoNumberPatternChecker_Test.  Neither of these remaining classes refer to any of the other classes that I am trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was!  I had forgotten that I had messed around with the code in the sandbox before creating the other classes.  I just copied and pasted the original code back into the classes from production and redeployed and it worked.